# Nissan Pathfinder 1999 won't change volume at all

Tags: nissan, audio, pathfinder

My Nissan Pathfinder 1999 that I just purchased (new teenage driver) has a functional radio and CD player, but the volume is inoperable. The knob spins and responds to pressing (to turn it off) but does not react when I turn it up or down.

What can I check or do next on my own to try to remedy this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Will it spin in the same direction continuously or does it have end stops?

Comment: Ha, when I first read this.. I'm thinking.. no the volume of your vehicle is fixed.  It doesn't change.  Need more interior volume to haul stuff, use a top rack.  Apologies.  No offense intended.

Comment: And as for radio volume, I'm nearly certain a 1999 volume knob was just a optical encoder feedback device. I don't believe that would be a variable capacitor type of device. The system would use digital counter (generally a led source).  You could spin it in any direction indefinitely. Now here's the issue.  Could be a bad encoder ring, bad led, or something else within the hardware.  Probably not an easy fix.